multirow overflow to the next cells
I am trying to make a table like this:



Type
Cathegory
Description
Reference




Long text
A
B
refs


*
C
D
refs


**
E
F
refs


covered text
G
H
refs



I
L
refs



M
N
refs



But I want the text "Long text" to span across 3 cells (*, and**), and same for the text "covered text". I tried using multicolumns, but the text from "Long text" overflowed and overlaps with the text "covered text"
EDITED: to include the whole code
This is the code I tried:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
% Adding the picture at the top
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|}
    \hline
    Type & Cathegory & Description & Reference \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{3cm}{\textbf{Problematic text} This text is too long and goes beyond the limits I want them to be} 
    & A & B & \cite{?} \\ \cline{2-4}
    & C & D & \cite{?}\\ \cline{2-4}
    & E & F & \cite{?} \\ \hline
    \textbf{This is covered} & G & H & \cite{?} \\ \cline{2-4}
    & I & J & \cite{?}\\ \cline{2-4}
    & K & L & \cite{?} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Welcome on TeX. StackExchange!

You can try to add \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}.

I dislike \multirow almost as much as I dislike caged tables.
You can make those long (or short) descriptions a subheader for each part of the table. Using a distinctive font shape such as italics will show the difference between them and the table data.
You also gain space for the descriptions and the citations.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\newcommand{\describe}[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\itshape #1}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X X @{}}
\toprule
Category & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Description} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{Reference} \\
\midrule
\describe{
  Problematic text. This text is too long 
  and goes beyond the limits I want them to be
} \\
A & B & \cite{?} \\
C & D & \cite{?}\\ 
E & F & \cite{?} \\
\midrule
\describe{This is covered} \\
G & H & \cite{?} \\
I & J & \cite{?}\\
K & L & \cite{?} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}



One way is that long text you have only in the first column, broken into more lines. With use of the tabularray package is simple to achieve, that rows  spanned by multi row cell has the same height:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} X[1.6, l,m] *{2}{X[c]} X[r] @{}},
             cell{2}{1} = {r=3}{},
             vspan =even, 
             }
    \toprule
Type    & Cathegory & Description   & Reference     \\ 
    \midrule
\textbf{Problematic text} This text is too long and goes beyond the limits I want them to be
%    &   &   &           \\
    & A & B & \cite{?}  \\  
    & C & D & \cite{?}  \\  
    & E & F & \cite{?}  \\  
    \midrule
\textbf{This is covered} 
    & G & H & \cite{?}  \\ 
    & I & J & \cite{?}  \\ 
    & K & L & \cite{?}  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


In the case, when  this long text should be in own row, than is not entirely clear, how your table should looks? Still have four columns? Please advise.
